# Ignore NaN when detrending 3-d array

Tags: arrays, matlab, nan

I'm using Matlab 2016a; I'm attempting to detrend a 3-dimensional array along the third dimension, but where there are missing values. It is critical that the values stay in the same positions in the array since the position relates to a geographic location. [image: 3-d array]

In this image, imagine that Page 2 has NaN at random locations but that Page 1 and Page 3 have complete data. Detrending along the 3rd dimension, some vectors will have three data points and some will have two. I need to be able to detrend along the third dimension using all available values. If I were to look at the values for the detrended Page 1 or Page 3, there should be no missing values (since there are always either 2 or 3 data points to use), but Page 2 would have NaN placeholders in the location where the NaN was located.

My question is: how can I detrend along the third dimension while ignoring NaN?

I've attempted using detrend3 (found on the Matlab file exchange: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/61328-detrend3?focused=7203929&tab=function), which works perfectly when detrending 3-d arrays with no missing values.

Detrending with NaN present produces an error. I've tried ignoring NaN and also setting NaN to -9999 and then ignoring that number, but have been unable to get these efforts to work.

Any guidance about what direction to go would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what detrending you want to perform? However could you change this line in the detrend3 function `t = (t(:)-mean(t))/std(t); ` to this `t = (t(:)-nanmean(t))/nanstd(t);` to ignore NaNs?

Comment: @Justin, as far as I can tell that wouldn't work. The NaNs are in the `A` matrix, not the `t` vector.

Comment: Can you confirm exactly what detrending you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The actual data I'm working with represents a time-series for NDVI (a measure of plant greeneess) for 17 years for Los Angeles. Each "layer" of the array is one day of measurements, with each matrix approximately 2,500 by 1,700 cells, representing the political boundary of Los Angeles. I have about 100 days of measurements and each data point represents NDVI for a 30 by 30 square meter pixel. Whenever a cloud is over a pixel it becomes NaN; about half of the days I am analyzing have clouds.

Comment: Is the issue still relevant? Are the measurement times evenly spaced? And just to be clear, your real matrix is about 2500x1700x100? Because for that scale it has to be efficient.

Comment: The measurement times are not evenly spaced, but detrend3 is able to take that into consideration through the use of a time vector.

Comment: I've been able to do detrending for the ~50 layers or so that I have with no clouds pretty quickly and with no problems. If I could figure out how to deal with clouds (NaN), I imagine the computation would still go pretty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function detrended = detrendNaN3(A,t)
%DETRENDNAN3 Detrends a matrix with NaNs into the third dimension
%   Input Arguments:
%       - A: NxMxK matrix
%       - t: 1xK time vector

% time to same format as A
t = bsxfun(@times,permute(t,[3 1 2]),ones(size(A)));
% where A == Nan, -> t = NaN
t(isnan(A)) = NaN;
%mean of time each pixel
xm = nanmean(t,3);
% mean of every pixel in A
ym = nanmean(A,3);
% calculate slope using least squares for every pixel
a = nansum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@minus,t,xm),bsxfun(@minus,A,ym)),3)./nansum(bsxfun(@minus,t,xm).^2,3);
% calculate intercept for every pixel
b = ym - a.*xm;
% calculate trend for every pixel
trend = bsxfun(@plus,b,bsxfun(@times,a,t));
% remove trend
detrended = A-trend;
end
```

Even tough the function is fully vectorised it could be written a bit faster - but it's currently very readable and with a 2500x1700x100 matrix it takes about 8 seconds which I deem acceptable.

An updated version is maintained [at the file exchange.](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/63749-detrendnan3)